# How to implement a page using modal windows and auto refresh divs when they are closed?

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to implement a page in which a user add Children or/and Adults through a modal window and after closing this modal window, the person added appears in the main page. It's like configuring a project in which you select people adding their information, by using a modal, and then when you are done you just confirm. But for that we want to display the already added people.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Yes, I have the controllers and models and stuff from CakePHP, and they work separately, as you might now how cake works. But I wonder how to do different adds or remove in the same page.

Comment: Yes, but I mean, it's important to have at least a piece of code. I think the important part here is how do you implement the modal window, ajax call or divs-and-css mix? Update the question with that code please.

Comment: That's the question, I don't know what to use actually. I was hoping someone could help me saying that I can do this using such thing or another thing. I don't have the codes for the modal windows, because I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm oversimplifying this because you're asking how to do it, not specific details. So keep in mind this is kind of a guideline, but you tweak and adjust to fit your needs.

So, this is what I would do:

1. Have the view where you want to display the list. Lets call it view.ctp, in there you'll have a table (or something more fancy) with the people added

   *Example code view.ctp*

   ```
   <table>
   <?
       foreach ($people as $id => $person) {
           echo '<tr><td>'.$person['name'].' '.$person['lastname'].'</td></tr>';
       }
   ?>
   </table>
   ```
2. Add a modal window. Let's use [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)'s (you need to search and see which do you prefer).

   *Example also in view.ctp*

   ```
   <div id="dialog-form" title="Add something">
   <?
       echo $this->Form->create().
            $this->Form->input('name').
            $this->Form->input('lastname').
       echo $this->Form->end();
   ?>
   </div>

   <script>
   $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             height: 300,
             width: 350,
             modal: true
         });
   });
   </script>
   ```
3. Control the submit of the form to do it via ajax call

   *Example also in view.ctp*

   ```
    //lets assume the form id is #form, ok?
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        /*validations and etc*/
        /* remember to prevent event propagation */
        var the_name = /* name taken out of the form */;
        var the_lastname = /* lastname taken out of the form */;

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(/*array for url to the add action*/);?>",
           data: { name: the_name, lastname: the_lastname }
        }).success(function( data) {
             /* lets say the table has a #table id */

             //add the "new" record to the table
             $('#table').append('<tr><td>'+the_name+' '+the_lastname+'</td></tr>');

             /* add code here to close the modal if you want */
        });
        return false;
    });
   ```

   What happens here is that on submit, the form does an ajax call to the action that actually adds the new person to the BD. Then the ajax call receives the result (could be a true or false, a json array, etc) and adds it to the table.
4. Create the add action that gets called

   *Example in... PeopleController.php or what you find appropriate*

   ```
   public function add() {
       if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
           $this->autoRender = false;
           //in $this->request->data should be the data passed by js

           if ($this->People->save($this->request->data))
               echo 'true :D';
           else
               echo 'false D:';
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

Aaaand... I think that covers all.

That's the summarized, crude way of doing what you want. You need to validate forms, decide what to do if the add doesn't work, what if it does, create the add action, etc. There are other ways of doing what you want, like reloading the view page after the submit of the form, load the form as another action... Well, it depends on how you want to do it. I hope I helped guide you towards some direction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Nunser. It is a great help!